# Async function always return observable

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, promise, observable

This below async function was created to populate the `userList` through the backend. But when this is called like this `await this.getUsers();` in `ngOnInit` it (userList) returns as an Observable. What is the missing part here?

```
async getUsers(): Promise<void> {
        if (this.empId) {
            this.userList = await this.empService.getEmpUsers(this.empId);
            console.log(this.userList); // return Observable {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like `empService.getEmpUsers` returns an observable, not a promise, so there's no point in `await`ing it

Comment: Use RxJS, not promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's HttpClient **always** returns an Observable. You need to turn it into a promise by using `RxJS 6` `.toPromise()` or `RxJS 7`:

```js
async getUsers(): Promise<void> {
        if (this.empId) {
            this.userList = await firstValueFrom(this.empService.getEmpUsers(this.empId))
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, when working in Angular YOU SHOULD ALWAYS USE RxJS. Never use promises, just work with observables since it's the way Angular was designed to work.

Comment: Where in the official documentation does it say that you're not allowed to use `Promise`? Why is RxJS providing `singleValueFrom`, `firstValueFrom` and `lastValueFrom` to get single-values from their streams? Why do all router guards accept the value, Promise and Observable of a value? Sometimes you're just interested in a single value from the stream as any Http call is a single emission stream. I am not sure why I got downvoted by answering what actually OP asked and accepted. While it is true that Angular's implementation heavily relies on RxJS that mantra of only use RxJS is rather false.

Comment: You can achieve the same using observables. Everything works with observables. An observable emiting one value is the same as a Promise. It is a good practice to use Observables only. You can mention in your answer the Promise workaround but the issue here is working with Promises instead of observables.

Comment: No. While I totally agree that one should embrace RxJS because it's easier to deal with streams of data than purely imperative code and Angular always has a way to combine and manipulate streams to get UI updates; the issue at hand is that OP was trying to `await` an `Observable` instead of a `Promise`. If you happen to disagree on how OP is using the web-framework you should address that with him 